# Breaking JIT optimisations with reflection

Tags: java, reflection, java-8, jit

When fiddling with unit tests for a highly-concurrent singleton class I stumbled upon the following weird behaviour (tested on JDK 1.8.0_162):

```
private static class SingletonClass {
    static final SingletonClass INSTANCE = new SingletonClass(0);
    final int value;

    static SingletonClass getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
    }

    SingletonClass(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {

    System.out.println(SingletonClass.getInstance().value); // 0

    // Change the instance to a new one with value 1
    setSingletonInstance(new SingletonClass(1));
    System.out.println(SingletonClass.getInstance().value); // 1

    // Call getInstance() enough times to trigger JIT optimizations
    for(int i=0;i<100_000;++i){
        SingletonClass.getInstance();
    }

    System.out.println(SingletonClass.getInstance().value); // 1

    setSingletonInstance(new SingletonClass(2));
    System.out.println(SingletonClass.INSTANCE.value); // 2
    System.out.println(SingletonClass.getInstance().value); // 1 (2 expected)
}

private static void setSingletonInstance(SingletonClass newInstance) throws NoSuchFieldException, IllegalAccessException {
    // Get the INSTANCE field and make it accessible
    Field field = SingletonClass.class.getDeclaredField("INSTANCE");
    field.setAccessible(true);

    // Remove the final modifier
    Field modifiersField = Field.class.getDeclaredField("modifiers");
    modifiersField.setAccessible(true);
    modifiersField.setInt(field, field.getModifiers() & ~Modifier.FINAL);

    // Set new value
    field.set(null, newInstance);
}
```

The last 2 lines of the main() method disagree on the value of INSTANCE - my guess is that JIT got rid of the method completely since the field is static final. Removing the final keyword makes the code output correct values.

Leaving aside your sympathy (or lack thereof) for singletons and forgetting for a minute that using reflection like this is asking for trouble - is my assumption correct in that JIT optimisations are to blame? If so - are those limited to static final fields only?

Comment: A singleton is a class for which only one instance can exist. Therefore, you don't have a singleton, you just have a class with a `static final` field. Besides that, it doesn't matter whether this reflection hack breaks due to JIT or concurrency.

Comment: @Holger this hack was was done in unit tests only as a try to mock the singleton for multiple test cases of a class that uses it. I don't see how concurrency could've caused it (there's none in the code above) and I'd really like to know what happened.

Comment: Well, you said “highly-concurrent singleton class” in your question and I say “*it doesn't matter*” what makes it break. So if your particular example code breaks due to JIT and you find a work-around for that and then, the real code changes from breaking due to JIT to breaking due to concurrency, what have you gained?

Comment: @Holger okay, the wording was a bit too strong there, sorry about that. What I meant was this - if we don't understand why something goes so horribly wrong we're prone to getting bitten by the same thing in the future, so I'd rather know the reason than assume "it just happens". Anyway, thanks for taking your time to answer!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Taking your question literally, “*…is my assumption correct in that JIT optimizations are to blame?*”, the answer is yes, it’s very likely that the JIT optimizations are responsible for this behavior in this specific example.

But since changing `static final` fields is completely off specification, there are other things that can break it similarly. E.g. the JMM has no definition for the memory visibility of such changes, hence, it is completely unspecified whether or when other threads notice such changes. They are not even required to notice it consistently, i.e. they may use the new value, followed by using the old value again, even in the presence of synchronization primitives.

Though, the JMM and the optimizer are hard to separate anyway here.

Your question “*…are those limited to static final fields only?*” is much harder to answer, as optimizations are, of course, not limited to `static final` fields, but the behavior of, e.g. non-static `final` fields, is is not the same and has differences between theory and practice as well.

For non-static `final` fields, modifications via Reflection are allowed in certain circumstances. This is indicated by the fact that `setAccessible(true)` is enough to make such modification possible, without hacking into the `Field` instance to change the internal `modifiers` field.

[The specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5.3) says:

> #### 17.5.3. Subsequent Modification of `final` Fields
>
> In some cases, such as deserialization, the system will need to change the `final` fields of an object after construction. `final` fields can be changed via reflection and other implementation-dependent means. The only pattern in which this has reasonable semantics is one in which an object is constructed and then the `final` fields of the object are updated. The object should not be made visible to other threads, nor should the `final` fields be read, until all updates to the `final` fields of the object are complete. Freezes of a `final` field occur both at the end of the constructor in which the `final` field is set, and immediately after each modification of a `final` field via reflection or other special mechanism.
>
> …
>
> Another problem is that the specification allows aggressive optimization of `final` fields. Within a thread, it is permissible to reorder reads of a `final` field with those modifications of a `final` field that do not take place in the constructor.
>
> > **Example 17.5.3-1. Aggressive Optimization of `final` Fields**
> >
> > ```
> > class A {
> >     final int x;
> >     A() { 
> >         x = 1; 
> >     } 
> >
> >     int f() { 
> >         return d(this,this); 
> >     } 
> >
> >     int d(A a1, A a2) { 
> >         int i = a1.x; 
> >         g(a1); 
> >         int j = a2.x; 
> >         return j - i; 
> >     }
> >
> >     static void g(A a) { 
> >         // uses reflection to change a.x to 2 
> >     } 
> > }
> > ```
> >
> > *In the `d` method, the compiler is allowed to reorder the reads of `x` and the call to `g` freely. Thus, `new A().f()` could return `-1`, `0`, or `1`.*

In practice, determining the right places where aggressive optimizations are possible without breaking the legal scenarios described above, are [an open issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8058164), so unless `-XX:+TrustFinalNonStaticFields` has been specified, the HotSpot JVM will not optimize non-static `final` fields the same way as `static final` fields.

Of course, when you don’t declare the field as `final`, the JIT can not assume that it will never change, though, in the absence of thread synchronization primitives, it may consider the actual modifications happening in the code path it optimizes (including the reflective ones). So it may still aggressively optimize the access, but only *as-if* the reads and writes still happen in the program order within the executing thread. So you’d only notice the optimizations when looking at it from a different thread without proper synchronization constructs.

Comment: it seems lots of people try to exploit this `final`s, but, though some have proven to be better performant, savings some `ns` is not worth breaking lots of other code. Reason why [Shenandoah is backing off on some of it's flags for example](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8229416)